# Android.How to send SMS without SIM card?

Tags: android, sms

I have a device with Android 4.4 in a board but it doesn't have a SIM card module.
Please, tell me , how i can emulate incoming SMS from my application?
I just wanna see standart notification aboute incoming sms.
I tried this example:

```
enter code here
private static void createFakeSms(Context context, String sender,
                                  String body) {
    byte[] pdu = null;
    byte[] scBytes  =PhoneNumberUtils.networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD("0000000000");
    byte[] senderBytes = PhoneNumberUtils.networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD(sender);
    int lsmcs = scBytes.length;
    byte[] dateBytes = new byte[7];
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    dateBytes[0] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
    dateBytes[1] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    dateBytes[2] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
    dateBytes[3] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
    dateBytes[4] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    dateBytes[5] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
    dateBytes[6] = reverseByte((byte) ((calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar
            .get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000 * 15)));
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bo.write(lsmcs);
        bo.write(scBytes,0,scBytes.length);
        bo.write(0x04);
        bo.write((byte) sender.length());
        bo.write(senderBytes,0,senderBytes.length);
        bo.write(0x00);
        bo.write(0x00); // encoding: 0 for default 7bit
        bo.write(dateBytes,0,dateBytes.length);
        try {
            String sReflectedClassName = "com.android.internal.telephony.GsmAlphabet";
            Class cReflectedNFCExtras = Class.forName(sReflectedClassName);
            Method stringToGsm7BitPacked = cReflectedNFCExtras.getMethod(
                    "stringToGsm7BitPacked", new Class[] { String.class });
            stringToGsm7BitPacked.setAccessible(true);
            byte[] bodybytes = (byte[]) stringToGsm7BitPacked.invoke(null,
                    body);
            bo.write(bodybytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        pdu = bo.toByteArray();
    }finally {

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
            "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
    intent.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { pdu });
    intent.putExtra("format", "3gpp");
    context.startService(intent);

}
private static byte reverseByte(byte b) {
    return (byte) ((b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4);
}
```

But when i call this function my application is crashed.
Please help me.